# How to get all intent that can be run?

Tags: android

I have used this code to get all intent that is in Settings:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pi.size(); i++) {
            try {

                if (pi.get(i).activities != null) {
                    int k = pi.get(i).activities.length;
                    Log.d(tag, "" + k + "  " + pi.get(i).packageName);

                    if (pi.get(i).packageName.toLowerCase().endsWith(
                            ".settings")) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < pi.get(i).activities.length; j++) {

                            Log.d(tag, "" + k + "  "
                                    + pi.get(i).activities[j].name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

but some of them can be runned with StartInetent and some of them can not because of internal usage , do you have any way to get all intent that can be runned with StartIntent ?

thanks

Comment: Could you provide a more detailed description of what you are trying to accomplish? I.e, what it is you mean by whether or not an Intent can run?